# Pyqgis: Some way to import shp(shapefile) to plugin(to create a toolbar of shpfileS), when we want a use a shpfile to active or deactive

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Some way to import shpfile(one shp file) in plugin, not go over the standard procedure(Select shp file, Toogle editing and Add features)-to do it with python, because I am trying a make a custom toolbar. Any solutions?
[image]

Comment: You have to add the button on the toolbar. Next connect it to a function that open a file selection dialog, take the result path and load in QGIS. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930908/how-to-order-the-files-the-way-it-is-selecting-in-pyqt) there is an example of custom file dialog

Comment: I know that, I work with that like in one plugin, I import another plugin: from Print.Print import Print #Import one plugin in another plugin; self.prikaz3=QAction(QIcon(self.plugin_dir + "/Icons/btnWordPrint.gif"),QCoreApplication.translate("Ur","Graficki prilog"), 
        self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.prikaz3.triggered.connect(self.BrziPrint)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.prikaz3) #Making a toolbar  def BrziPrint(self): 
  sg = Print(self.iface)
     sg.run()#call a function, ut how it work with shpfile because we must call a shp file,call toogle editing,call add feature